# Read Google Location History KML in R

Tags: r, kml

I'm working with a KML file generated by Google Location History takeout. Its structure is slightly different from a usual KML: each waypoint is recorded with 2 same-level tags (`<when>` and `<gx:coord>`):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2'>
 <Document>
  <Placemark>
   <open>1</open>
   <gx:Track>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <when>2011-03-20T17:33:11Z</when>
    <gx:coord>37.7605394 55.7806361 0</gx:coord>
    <when>2011-05-29T15:53:14Z</when>
    <gx:coord>4.5734683 45.0497192 0</gx:coord>
    <when>2011-06-09T16:45:50Z</when>
    <gx:coord>4.5736926 45.0501430 0</gx:coord>
   </gx:Track>
  </Placemark>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

On my understanding, `readOGR()` can't work with this kind of data. Are there any other solutions?

P.S. Requested code and output:

```
ogrListLayers("file.kml")
# [1] "Layer #0"
# attr(,"driver")
# [1] "KML"
# attr(,"nlayers")
# [1] 1

readOGR("file.kml","Layer #0")
# Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding,
# use_iconv = use_iconv,  :    Cannot open layer
```

Comment: My empirical evidence trumps your understanding. `map = readOGR("map.kml","map")` works perfectly for me. Did you try? What do you expect to read in?

Comment: @Spacedman yes I tried, it gives an error: `Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer`

Comment: Put that in your question, and show your code. Also show what `ogrListLayers("file.kml")` does.

Comment: "map" was the name of the layer in my file. You need to use `readOGR("file.kml","Layer #0")` since that's the layer name in your file (which you can get from the `ogrListLayers` output).

Comment: sure, I did that

Comment: okay that's weird now. If I cut and paste your KML example into a file it works for me. Is that what you are trying to read in or is it some other file? Can you share that file if so?

Comment: just tried again in a fresh R session, with exactly this copy-pasted kml. Error message slightly different, but still: `Error in readOGR("file.kml", "Layer #0") : no features found
In addition: Warning message:
In ogrFIDs(dsn = dsn, layer = layer) : no features found`. No idea what's wrong there...